# grab multiple lines of input file based on value in a certain line

Tags: perl

I am slowly learning more of PERL and need some help with an issue I am facing.  I have this input file from an excel spreadsheet given in csv format.  In the spreadsheet they will merge cells and give a list of values if one of the cells value in the line has "LOV".  I need to grab the next X lines that go with that LOV and then output that LOV into a single line with other values from the same line.  So here is what the input file looks like:

```
Intro |Input|Middle |PPP|Requirement|Manual|Text|||
Intro |Input|END |PPP|Design|Manual|LOV|"Ancestory
Red
Blue
Purple
Orange
Yellow"||
Intro |Output|END |PPP|Design|Automatic|Number|||
```

The file looks like that and will just repeat with data similar to above. Output will be put in different files based on the Text,LOV,Number ETC.  I need to get the LOV output to show like this:

```
Intro |END |LOV|"Ancestory Red Blue Purple Orange Yellow"||
```

I am completely lost on how to solve this.  Can I use an array to grab the next lines within the quotations?  I can grab every other line fine but so far this is what my logic is looking like.

```
my @LOV;
while(<file1>){

            my($line) = $_;
            chomp $line;
            if $line == "LOV"
            {

                push @LOV, $_;
                while (<file1>) 
                {
                    last if /^$/;
                    push @LOV, $_;
                }                       
                    print file2 "$output\n";
            }
            else
            {


                if ("NUMBER")
                {
                    print file3"output";
                }
                else if ("Text")
                {
                    print file4"output";
                }

            }
```

I don't know if I should read the file a different way but any suggestions or help would be great!  Thank you for anything you can offer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just curious. What book are you using to learn Perl?

Your coding style is way, way out of date. You're not the first person who is learning Perl and is using a syntax style that dates from the late 1980s, so I'm just curious what books are on the market (or webpages) that people are using to learn Perl.

One of the wonderful things about Perl is that it has lots of modules that can handle much of what you want. In this case, you need to use the [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.32/lib/Text/CSV.pm) module that will do all the heavy lifting for you when reading that column with the embedded NL in them:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;
use feature qw(say);

use Text::CSV;

my $spreadsheet = Text::CSV->new (
    {
        binary      => 1,
        sep_char    => "|",
        eol         => $/,
    }
);
open my $file, "<:crlf", "text.csv";

while ( my $row = $spreadsheet->getline($file) ) {
    my @columns = @{ $row };
    for my $field ( @columns ) {
        $field =~ s/\n/, /g;
    }
    say join " | ", @columns;
}
```

This prints out:

```
Intro  | Input | Middle  | PPP | Requirement | Manual | Text |  |  | 
Intro  | Input | END  | PPP | Design | Manual | LOV | Ancestory, Red, Blue, Purple, Orange, Yellow |  | 
Intro  | Output | END  | PPP | Design | Automatic | Number |  |  |
```

Unfortunately, it uses *object oriented notation* which can be a bit confusing, but I'll try to break this apart bit by bit:

First, you might need to install `Text::CSV`. You can do that with the following command:

```
$ cpan install Text::CSV
```

This should work fine on Windows if you have [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com) installed or ActivePerl.

If you are on Linux or the Mac, you need to do this:

```
$ sudo cpan install Text::CSV
```

And, you'll need your *root* password.

Once installed, you can also install `Text::CSV_XS` if you so desire. This makes Text::CSV faster, especially if you have really, really large spreadsheets.

Let's take this line-by-line:

The first four lines that start with `use` are standard pragmas that should be in all of your programs. The `strict` will guard against sloppy errors, and `warnings` will help you catch other types of errors like using variables that don't contain any value.

The `my $spreadsheet = Text::CSV->new` is creating an *object*. This is what you'll use to operate on your file. This has three parameters. The `binary` allows for multiple lined data (like what you have). The `sep_char` says that your separator isn't a comma, but the `|` symbol. The `eol` I'm not so sure is important -- especially since I handle the Unix/Windows issue when I open the file with `<:crlf` which will convert instances of `crlf` to just `lf`.

I open my file and use the `getline` method to read in my rows. This will read in your multiple long rows without you having to count lines or anything.

The:

```
my @columns = @{ $rows };
```

is a bit tricky. Perl variables are all based upon single values. Sure you have hashes and arrays, but they're a list of single values. Sometimes, you need to deal with values as a set, and Perl uses References. `$rows` is a pointer to an array of my columns. I am *dereferencing* the reference and creating a true array called `@columns`. Read the [Reference Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for more information.

`$field =~ s/\n/, /g;` is merely replacing any instance of a *new line* in a field with commas.

Finally, I just print everything out with the `say` command and by using [join](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) to join my rows into a single string that I can print out and make them `|` separated.

Notice I don't need to count and handle the multiple line rows. The `Text::CSV` module does it for me. It's short, and easy to understand, and will work even if the multiple rowed field is in the middle of the spreadsheet.

Comment: I feel like I need a snifter of brandy and perhaps a nap after reading that answer. Excellent!

Comment: I have been learning on the fly.  No book and no real teacher just online on tutorials and through other individuals.  I can tell now how wrong I was in my original code.  Thank you for this answer, it is far more than I ever expected.  Is there a book you might recommend?